# Google Maps URLs, how to add a personal name to destination point?

Tags: google-maps-urls

I'm using Google Maps URLs from my web site page to provide a direction to my user. It works fine and launch automatically Google Map app. on mobile phone. To do that I'm using the lat, long destination coordinates extracted from my database. Each destination point have a name in my database, like PA_1155 or LDN_078... I would like to display that name on the destination point on the map but I didn't find anyway to do that. Is there any additional parameter that I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, the [Maps URLs documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls) does not include information on any facility/parameter you could use to pass this arbitrary "destination name" and have it be displayed in the resulting Google Maps view.

Purely speculatively, this is likely a deliberate design choice to prevent manipulation of the resulting maps to show inaccurate information to end users. In the interest of protecting its users, I would say it's unlikely that Google would ever enable this sort of functionality.

Comment: Thx for that. This is what I expected from Google no more, no less.